# The sum of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{4n+3}{5^n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

What is the sum of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{4n+3}{5^n}\right)$ ?
I got that the series converges and the sum seems to be $5$.
When trying to explicitly get the sum, I tried to find the appropriate function whose Maclaurin series would be this sum.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{4n+3}{5^n}\right)=2-\frac{2+N}{5^N}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{4n+3}{5^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{4n}{5^n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{3}{5^n}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
derive it
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
multiply by $x$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }nx^{n}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$
at $x=1/5$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{4n}{5^{n}}=4\frac{1/5}{(1-1/5)^2}$$
the second series is geometric series
$$3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }x^n=3\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$$
find the value at $x=1/5$

Comment: You really don't need to subtract one before taking the derivative.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews but I think the $n$ was $1$

Comment: Yes, but what is $nx^n$ when $n=0$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{5^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=n}^\infty \frac{1}{5^m}$$

Answer (score 2):

a telescoping way,

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{n+1}{5^{n-1}}\right)$$-$ $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{n+2}{5^n}\right)$

Comment: I was thinking in this line. But we need to prove the convergence, right?  Also, how to derive this relation?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(4n+3)x^n&=4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\\
&=4(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n+1})'-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\\
&=4(\frac{x}{1-x})'-\frac{1}{1-x}\\
&=\frac{x+3}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}
$$

Set $x=\frac{1}{5}$, we have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4n+3}{5^n}=5$.